# Añadir código php dentro de una etiqueta a

Tags: php, html, href

En el footer de toda la web, tengo creado un apartado de newsletter, donde el botón de suscríbete es una etiqueta a.

Me gustaría que al apretar el botón, me ejecutara un código php. Ese código es un shortcode de mailchimp de wordpress, que hace que aparezca un popup con el formulario.

Cómo puedo hacer que apretando al botón, se me ejecute el código php.

Gracias

```
 <a>Suscríbete</a>
```

Este seria el código php:

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="32871"]' );?>`

Comment: No.. así me muestra el formulario encima del bóton.

Comment: Crea un formulario y ejecutas el código PHP desde el action, que el botón suscríbete sea el submit. Es la forma más sencilla.

Comment: ```<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="32871"]' );?>">Suscríbete</a>``` Probaste con href?

Comment: Jheyman, necesito que solo se vea el botón y una vez le das aparezca el pop de mailchimp, creo que así no  me solucionaria el problema.

Comment: Si Javier, de esta manera, me aparece el el formulario de mailchimp, pero el Suscríbete no se ve..

Comment: Esto no es posible sin pasar por Ajax. El shortcode está del lado del servidor (PHP) y tu elemento `a` está en el cliente. Por tanto, debes escuchar los clicks del anchor tag y lanzar una petición Ajax que te ejecute el shortcode en el servidor.